# Cannot open Ubuntu on Chromebook via Crouton ubuntu.session does not exist

Tags: ubuntu, chromebook, crouton

I opened my chromebook today and tried to go to my ubuntu via crouton, but it did not work. I'm getting the following error:

```
chronos@localhost / $ sudo startunity
Entering /mnt/stateful_partition/crouton/chroots/precise...
-su: 27: [[: not found
awk: fatal: cannot open file `/usr/share/gnome-session/sessions/ubuntu.session' for reading (No such file or directory)
Unmounting /mnt/stateful_partition/crouton/chroots/precise...
```

I don't remember when I last used ubuntu but I know I haven't changed any settings. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by updating crouton. Once the update completed, the error was resolved